# Google Drive API response when listing files and retrieving specific fields

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the following query to retrieve files from a specific folder in Google Drive and fetch certain fields like 'owners':

```
results = self.service.files().list(fields="files('owners')).execute()
```

Until recently, this query used to return the requested fields correctly. However, now the response is an empty dictionary. Has there been any recent change in the API that might be causing this behavior? Or perhaps is there any modification needed in the way I'm making the query to retrieve these fields? I would appreciate any help or advice to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Comment: what happens  if you do fields = * ?

Comment: About your showing script and `this query used to return the requested fields correctly.`, I think that `fields="files('owners')` is not enclosed by the double quote. I'm worried that your script has an error. But, you say `However, now the response is an empty dictionary`. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your tested script. If you want to retrieve the metadata of `owners`, I think that `fields="files('owners'))` is `fields="files(owners)"`. So, when you test `results = self.service.files().list(fields="files(owners)").execute()`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo returns a lot of fields, but not the "owners" field, which is it I want

Comment: @Tanaike sorry, it was a copy and paste error, but it was fine, and it didn't return anything

Comment: try doing a file.get on the file id.  do you see it there?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike sorry, it was a copy and paste error, but it was fine, and it didn't return anything`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply.